# how to pass java-script array into JAVA array using AJAX

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json, jsp

I am trying to post an array of JavaScript into an array of Strings in Java. It goes like this...

My JavaScript code:

```
var quantity_arr = new Array();

for (var i=0; i< <%= cart.size() %>; i++) {
    quantity_arr[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity")[i].value;
}
xmlhttp.send("sum_of_order="+sum_of_order+"&credits_number="+credits_no+"&credit_card_number="+credit_card_number+"&quantity_arr="+quantity_arr);
```

This is my Java code:

```
String[]  myParams =new String[cart.size()];
String order_id=Integer.toString(temp);
String customer_id="'"+session.getAttribute("user_id")+"'";
String date= "15/29/12";
String sum=request.getParameter("sum_of_order");
String credit_card= "'"+request.getParameter("credit_card_number")+"'";
String credits="'"+request.getParameter("credits_number")+"'";
myParams = request.getParameterValues("quantity_arr");
```

All the params works fine except the `myParams array` that gets nothing. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String[]  myParams = request.getParameterValues("quantity_arr").split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see: http://support.dataweb.com/Help/default.view?Topic=Request.getParameterValues()

Basically, you cannot pass directly `"quantity_arr="+quantity_arr` but you have to use:

```
"quantity_arr="+quantity_arr[0]+"&quantity_arr="+quantity_arr[1]+"&quantity_arr="+quantity_arr[2]+ ...
```

Comment: thank you
did it allready, thought that a more sophisticated way